# Почему одноврЕмЕнный, но заблаговрЕменный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Нормативное ударение в слове "одновременный" вариативно — и *одновр**е**менный*, и *одноврем**е**нный* являются равноправными (БОС; М., 2016). (В некоторых словарях одновр**е**менный лишь допустимый вариант.) В родственном прилагательном "заблаговременный" нормативное ударение *заблаговр**е**менный*, и я даже не нашел упоминания о варианте *заблаговрем**е**нный*.

Почему не кодифицирован этот вариант? С чем связано нормативное ударение *заблаговр**е**менный*?

Comment: Насчёт «равноправия» словарь сильно преувеличил, а «некоторые словари» надо бы огласить.

Comment: @shampar ну, если угодно, "Орфоэпический словарь русского языка" под ред. Н. А. Еськовой (М., 2015). Только неясно, какое преувеличение вы здесь видите.

Comment: Дело в том, что некоторые словари считают (если такое слово употребимо к словарям) допустимыми оба ударения только у наречия «одновременно», напр. словарь под ред. М.Н Свиридовой.

Comment: @shampar думаю, что такие словари создавались не очень последовательными лексикографами )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова даёт помету  "канцеляризм устаревший, устаревшая форма" для прилагательного ЗАБЛАГОВРЕМЕННЫЙ - сделанный заблаговременно. Наречие осталось в современном пользовании, но как книжное слово -"загодя сделанное". Слово старое - и ударение старое,  XIX века, когда ударение было неподвижным для этой основы.

Нормы русского языка со временем меняются, и правила постановки ударения в слове «одновременно» за последние столетия изменились тоже. В словаре Владимира Даля, составленном в середине XIX века, правильное ударение было  «одноврЕменно». В «Словаре неправильностей русской речи» Долопчева, вышедшего в 1909 году, в качестве нормативного также указывался именно этот вариант.
Некоторые из авторов более современных словарей и справочников русского языка до сих пор отдают преимущество ударению «одноврЕменно»,  считая, однако, вариант с акцентом на четвертом слоге «одновремЕнно» допустимым. Однако эту точку зрения можно считать устаревшей.

Так, уже в 1960 году в словаре Ожегова фиксируется двойная норма ударения в слове «одновременный», и варианты произношения даны как равноправные, без указания на предпочтительность того или иного варианта.

Такой же точки зрения придерживались и многие другие составители словарей: двойное ударение в слове «одновременный» фигурировало в «Орфоэпическом словаре», выпущенном издательством «Русский язык» в 1983 году, в словаре Российской Академии Наук (2003 год издания), словаре под редакцией Лопатина и многих других словарях и справочниках.

В орфоэпическом словаре Резниченко, внесенного в официальный список словарей, содержащих нормы русского языка как государственного, также указан двойной вариант нормы

Есть такое мнение: раньше слова с разным ударением различались по смыслу: "одноврЕменно" - происходившее в одно и то же время, а "одновремЕнно" (разговорный вариант одновремённо) - события общей эпохи, одних времён, как современный, современник - с одного времени.

Своевременный - в своё время, единовременный - один раз=единственное время. Таким образом, ударение зависело от модели словообразования: в  одно время//одного времени.